# How to make an component flash in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React. I want to create a component when the state is updated, it will fade out and fade in again. Could someone please tell me how to do that like the JQuery here:

```
$("#someElement").fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use CSS animations and `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`.

More information, and an example, can be found here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html